# How do I access a boolean from another class in the constructor of an object?

Tags: java, constructor, boolean

So I have a main class, and in this class I have a boolean called test. I want to be able to flip it either on or off after a certain amount of time, so I have a class called BooleanFlipCounter. Below

```
public class BooleanFlipCounter implements Runnable {
    int seconds;
    boolean booleanToFlip;
    boolean setOnOrOff;

    // Seconds is seconds before flip.
    // booleanToFlip is where you define where you use it which boolean to use.
    // setOnOrOff is true or false, whether it flips it to on or off after a
    // certain time.

    public BooleanFlipCounter(int secondss, boolean booleanToFlips, 
                              boolean setOnOrOffs) {
        seconds = secondss;
        booleanToFlip = booleanToFlips;
        setOnOrOff = setOnOrOffs;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        while (seconds <= 0) {

            System.out.println("1: " + booleanToFlip + " : " + setOnOrOff);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            seconds--;
            System.out.println("Minused");

        }

        if (setOnOrOff == true) {
            Main.test = true;
            System.out.println("2: " + booleanToFlip + " : " + setOnOrOff);
        } else if (setOnOrOff == false) {
            Main.test = false;
            System.out.println("3: " + booleanToFlip + " : " + setOnOrOff);
        }

    }

}
```

I want to be able to access "test" when I create a new BooleanFlipCounter. How do I access it as the boolean object, and not as an actual boolean? If that makes any sence.

Comment: You don't show the code from Main.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html

Answer (score 0):

A `boolean` variable is not an object, and you can't access it "as" an object.  If you want a reference to a `boolean` variable, you need to use a reference to the object that contains it.

You could define an interface:

```
public interface Testable {
    boolean isTest();
    void setTest(boolean test);
}
```

Then you can make your `Main` class implement `Testable` in terms of its internal `test` flag, and make `BooleanFlipCounter` take a reference to a `Testable` object that it should manipulate.

(Note that this requires you to create an *instance* of your `Main` class, or at least of something that implements the `Testable` interface.  If the `Main.test` flag is currently a static variable, consider making it non-static.  You can have your static `main` method just create a `new Main()` and call a method on it to do the real work.)